# Python SQLite3, how to access the database from two different scripts concurrently?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to access the database while the writing to the database from a different script.

The write part

```
def tick_entry(timestamp,ltp):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('bnf_tick.db', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES, timeout=20)

     c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute('INSERT INTO bnftick (timestamp, close) VALUES (?,?)',
          (timestamp,ltp))

    conn.commit()

    c.close()

    conn.close()
```

I am running a `for loop` on a `pandas dataframe` and writing the data using `tick_entry` form above.

I want to be able to access the database while the loop is running but I keep getting:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

In real-time(right now I am feeding in old data) the data should be a little more sporadic. I am trying to figure out if I will be able to access the `database` while it is being written to by the above function.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Only one connection can have an open write transaction at a time (and when it does no read transactions are allowed unless it's a WAL database) So if one gets a locked error, wait a short time for the transaction to be committed and the write lock released, and try again.

Comment: @Shawn thanks. Am I correct to assume I can keep the connection to the database in both scripts but while the `db` is being written into I cannot read it?

Comment: Unless you use WAL journal mode, yeah. https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html

Answer (score 0):

SQLite databases are not able to be modified by more than one process at a time. This is a known design limitation, and is not possible to code around.

Comment: Not true. You can have any number of readers, or a single writer, but not both at once (unless using WAL mode).

Comment: @Shawn Thank you for clarifying, I've edited my post to reflect this.

Comment: I am only trying to read in the other instance. i.e. one script writes to the SQLite database and the other reads from the DB. Is there a specific way to open in "read only"?